# Spring MVC application deployed on Tomcat does not run on IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, tomcat7

I try to run a basic Spring MVC application, like the one [here](https://github.com/geowarin/spring-mvc-examples/tree/master/mvc-base) (or also the Spring MVC tutorial [here](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-web/tree/master/4/complete)).

I just open the project in IntelliJ, import it on a Tomcat 7 instance, and start the Tomcat server. But when I try to reach the `http://localhost:8080`, I get a 404 error.

The project I downloaded from GitHub provides 2 ways to start the application, with `mvn jetty:run` or `mvn tomcat7:run`. When I run any of these commands (outside IntelliJ), the application starts succesfully, and the web page is displayed correctly on the `http://localthost:8080` URL, which led me think that the problem comes from IntelliJ.

Adding some debug information, it appears that when run under IntelliJ, the `WebInitializer` class is loaded, but not the `WebConfig` class, even if the method `WebInitializer.getServletConfigClasses()` is called.

With `mvn jetty:run` or `mvn tomcat7:run`, both classes are correctly instantiated.

Unfortunately, I have no error at all in any logs provided by Tomcat / IntelliJ, so I'm a bit lost.

What I am doing wrong, or what I've missed in the configuration of my project in IntelliJ?

Thanks

Technical info: Java 7, Tomcat 7, IntelliJ Ultimate 12.1.4, Spring 3.2.2.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved. I was using Tomcat **7.0.8** in IntelliJ, while the tomcat7-maven-plugin relies on Tomcat **7.0.30**.
So I downloaded the latest version, **7.0.42**, and now IntelliJ is working fine.

I'm not sure what feature was missing in the 7.0.8, but IntelliJ was not able to start my Spring MVC application correctly.